# How to pass UniqueRequestToken to AWS mechanical turk using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to use the UniqueRequestToken parameter of create_hit as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html). It doesn't show up as a parameter in [boto.mturk.connection.MTurkConnection.create_hit](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/mturk.html?highlight=request#boto.mturk.connection.MTurkConnection.create_hit). I tried to use it, guessing that it would be called `unique_request_token`, and got the following:

```
TypeError: create_hit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique_request_token'
```

Does boto simply not support that parameter? Is there any way to get around this, short of patching the boto client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is not implemented by Boto.](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mturk/connection.py#L179) You need to patch Boto to add this if you want to continue using Boto.

Alternatively, you can use my [Python mTurk API](http://mturkconsultant.com/blog/index.php/2013/01/my-python-mechanical-turk-api-mturkcore-py/). You'd make this request like:

```
from mturkcore import MechanicalTurk
m = MechanicalTurk()
m.create_request("CreateHIT", {..."UniqueRequestToken":"..."})
```

I personally believe mine is a better option because it uses the exact names in the documentation and supports the entire API. If a new name is added, it will (hopefully) be supported by mine even if I do not update :)

Best of luck!